# How to extend generated xaml.cs file? UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

When creating a new UserControl in UWP the following code behind xaml.cs file is generated.

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I would like to update this file so we can have better logging when things like the xaml fails to parse correctly.

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        try
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //do all the logging
        }
    }
}
```

Whether this is done by extending UserControl or just doing the above (or some other option), I would like to avoid having to do this manually for all future user controls that are created. Is there any way that I can update/extend the code that is generated when we create a new user control / xaml.cs file so that I don't have to manually add the extra logging each time?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more, are u saying u dont watch to write try catch for like u did here for every user control u create?

Comment: Yep. I want it to be generated along with the rest of the code that is generated.

Comment: Yes you can alter the cs file but No, this won't catch parsing errors.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

**UserControl** is part of the **uwp SDK** and you can not edit that class itself. However you can create a child from usercontrol, within its constructor call constructor of its parent ( **base** ). Then you can create child of this new class to create your user controls and then work on wiring it up to the UI part as well which can be more complicated. So the simplest way to error log your xaml parsing right now is the way you are already doing it. You have to put that try catch. You can just create a snippet and every time you create a new user control just use that snippet on its constructor maybe that can save you some time.

Comment: I wasn't talking about editing the class itself. I was talking about extending UserControl either by using it as a base class or some other way.

The question I am asking is if I can update where the code behind is generated so it will either automatically include my new class the extends UserControl or include the try catch.

Comment: basically u want the try catch automatically generated with every user control, which is not posible because for that you hve to edit the generator of usercontrol, which you cannot do.